# Including files(asm) with assembly

Tags: assembly

I have a school assembly project to do, and I'm trying to keep organztion by spliting the code to multiple files.
I tried going with

```
include Utilities.asm
```

and when I try to run the assembler on it I get this following error:

```
**Error** BASE.ASM(5) Need file name after INCLUDE
```

The file is in the same folder of the the main file(BASE.ASM).
so I want help to realize what I am doing wrong?
Thanks very much for any kind of help

Comment: You haven't provided a whole lot of details. If you're using TASM in IDEAL mode you should probably put quotes around the filename (`"Utilities.asm"`)

Comment: When it's on IDEAL it's gives me other error **FATAL** BASE.ASM(5) Can't locate file Utilities.asm , by the way what other details you want to know?

Comment: One other thing that I forgot to mention is that with other file(Renderer.asm) it's actually working...

Comment: I actually manged to fix it with a help of my friend, thanks for the help Michael!

Comment: In EMU8086 you have to place the included files in the "inc" folder.